# Log4J in jar - properties

Tags: java, jar, log4j

I have a problem with the log4J in my project.  It works fine in Eclipse but when I put it in a runnable jar I get issue's like :

[image]

My structure looks something like this :

[image]

So I believe there is a problem with loading my Log4J property file's.

I load them by :

[image]

Comment: From my experience, the properties file should be in the same directory as the jar file than inside of it. You should also consider using getResources().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They belong in the project CLASSPATH.  If you put the log4j.properties or log4j.xml in the CLASSPATH you'll have no problem finding them.

It's another example of how using Eclipse without knowing what it's doing is harmful.  How many people come here and say "It works fine in Eclipse but fails without it"?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally not how you configure log4j. Normally, you'd make a file named log4j.properties and not call the PropertyConfigurator at all. You can put that file at the root of your jar, or in an outside directory added to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

property  file must be inside the CLASSPATH. there for add it in to the call path by `Right Click the Project --> Build Path --> Use as Source Folder`